# Extract all images from a Joomla article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have this code that extracts the first image from an article in joomla:

```
<?php preg_match('/<img (.*?)>/', $this->article->text, $match); ?>
<?php echo $match[0]; ?>
```

Is there a way to extract all the images that are available in the article and not only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may suggest first to not use Regular Expressions to parse HTML. You should use an [appropiate parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) such as [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) which uses libxml.

Then you may query for the desired tags you want. Something like this may work (untested):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->loadHTML($htmlSource);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//img';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  // $entry->getAttribute('src')
}
```

Comment: I like this approach since I have access to the attributes and i let xpath do the job. You also answered first so you win. Thanx

Comment: just to mention that I used it again. To bad I can't also like again :P

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). And you'll want to modify the pattern like so to take into account the trailing '/' inside the img tag.

```
$str = '<img src="asdf" />stuff more stuff <img src="qwerty" />';
preg_match_all('/<img (.*?)\/>/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src="asdf" />
            [1] => <img src="qwerty" />
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="asdf" 
            [1] => src="qwerty" 
        )

)
```

Comment: @Alexander's approach is the better one for parsing HTML.

Comment: hehe and I came back to use this. Well it works but if the image has attributes id does not clear them at array [1][0]